# Count time within time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to count amount of time in specified range. For example, I have range (let's call it peak hours) `12:00-14:00`. And i have another range(visit time), that might change, for ex `9:00-15:00`. How do I get intersected hours for these 2 ranges?

As result I would like to get something like: `{peak_hours: 2, regular_hours: 4}`
Here `peak_hours` value is `2` as that many peak hours overlap with regular hours.  And, `regular_hours` value is `4` as that many regular hours do not overlap with peak hours.

I'm kinda stuck with solution. I tried to use time ranges, but that didn't work for me. This is the code

```
peak_hours_range = Time.parse(peak_hour_start)..Time.parse(peak_hour_end)

session_range = visit_start..visit_end

inters = session_range.to_a & peak_hours_range.to_a
```

But this throws me type error

Comment: I don't understand what peak and regular hours are.

Comment: thats just 2 different ranges. In the end - i want to know how many regular hours intersects with peak hours

Comment: @Jordan, I don't doubt that this is a dup, but not a dup of the referenced question, which deals with overlapping dates.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think at least one of the answer to the referenced question solves OP's problem, but nevertheless I've reopened this one.

Comment: Question is not clear - what you mean by intersected hours?  Can you explain your expected output?

Comment: @WandMaker By intersected hours - i mean intersected ranges of time. And as result i would like to get amount of hours from range(visit time) that intersects with range(peak hours)

Comment: How did you get 4 hours of intersection in regular hours for peak hours of 2? If peak hours were 8:00-10:00, what would be output?

Comment: @WandMaker with your peak hours output would be: {peak_hours: 1, regular_hours: 5}

Comment: What does 1 for peak hour mean? Is it because 1 hour of peak times is out of regular hour range or inside the range?  Similarly, why regular hours value is 5?

Comment: 1 peak hour because from range 9:00-15:00 only 1 hour inside range of 8:00 - 10:00. 5 regular hours - thats just `total hours - peak hours`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, we find the total hours in both ranges included, and then remove the peak hours from it to get effective regular hours.

```
require "time"

peak_hour_start = "12:00"
peak_hour_end = "14:00"

regular_hour_start = "9:00"
regular_hour_end = "15:00"

ph = (Time.parse(peak_hour_start).hour...Time.parse(peak_hour_end).hour).to_a
#=> [12, 13]
rh = (Time.parse(regular_hour_start).hour...Time.parse(regular_hour_end).hour).to_a
#=> [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
total = (ph + rh).uniq
#=> [12, 13, 9, 10, 11, 14]
r = {peak_hours: (ph - rh).size, regular_hours: (total - ph).size}
#=> {:peak_hours=>2, :regular_hours=>4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to find the intersection yourself.

```
inters = nil

intersection_min = [peak_hour_start, visit_start].max
intersection_max = [peak_hour_end, visit_end].min

if intersection_min < intersection_max
  inters = [intersection_min, intersection_max]
end

inters
```

Of course this can be cleaned up by extracting it out into it's own method.